# GSTIN Validation through condition not working in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, validation

I have written Perl code for validating GSTIN Number which is related to India’s tax according to the following rules:

- The first two digits represent the state code as per Indian Census 2011. Every state has a unique code.
- The next ten digits will be the PAN number of the taxpayer
- The thirteenth digit will be assigned based on the number of registration within a state
- The fourteenth digit will be Z by default
- The last digit will be for check code. It may be an alphabet or a number.

Following is the code:

```
my $gst_number_input = '35AABCS1429B1AX';

my $gst_number_character_count = length($gst_number_input);

my $gst_validation =~ /\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}[Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}/;

if ($gst_number_character_count == 15 && $gst_number_input =~ $gst_validation) {
    print "GST Number is valid";
} else {
    print "Invalid GST Number";
}
```

I have an invalid GSTIN input entered in the code. So when I run the script, I get:

`GST Number is valid`

Instead I should get the error because the GSTIN input is invalid:

`Invalid GST Number`

Can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is invalid `35AABCS1429B1AX` because the the value ends on `AX` where the A should be a Z according to the pattern. Note that you can omit `{1}` from the pattern and the Z does not have to be between square brackets `[Z]`

Comment: I know its invalid. I want the code to be corrected , so that if i enter the valid input, it says valid , or else invalid

Comment: Change the `[Z]` to `A` or use `[A-Z]` See https://regex101.com/r/UHaSTb/1

Comment: No, as per the rules, 14th character is always Z. I want to know what's wrong in the code . Not to manipulate the regex based on the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part you are using `=~` where is should be an equals sign `=`

`my $gst_validation =~ /\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}[Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}/;`

If you want to use is as a variable, you could use `qr`

Note that you can omit `{1}` from the pattern and you don't have to use the square brackets around `[Z]`

You code might look like

```
my $gst_number_input = '35AABCS1429B1AX';
my $gst_number_character_count = length($gst_number_input);
my $gst_validation = qr/\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z][A-Z\d]Z[A-Z\d]/;

if ($gst_number_character_count == 15 && $gst_number_input =~ $gst_validation) {
    print "GST Number is valid";
} else {
    print "Invalid GST Number";
}
```